# How to add the Entity Data Model in ASP.NET 5 Template

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I didn't find any option in add> new item in the project file.This type of project does not support files edmx ? What is the right way to develop a project in Asp.net 5 MVC 6 using Entity Framework 7

Comment: what did you do so far , you  need to give us more your question details

Comment: I mean how to add edmx in asp.net 5 template  in visual studio 2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per EF team [*announcement*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/10/21/ef7-what-does-code-first-only-really-mean.aspx), EF Core (formerly called EF7) will focus on code first and there will be *no* support for designer based EF models (i.e. EDMX files).

Code First is the only way you can develop your data access code in EF Core.

Comment: ASP.NET Core RC2 helps any help in db first for support designer based EF model??

Comment: I haven't tried it but I think you can use EF 6 in your ASP.NET Core app depends on your target platform (net451 or .net core).